# Reading string elements in C#

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing

I have a html code parsed in a string. I want to read table tag  in the string and read it separately and then store it to a JSON file.
I am not able to identify table tag if I try to export JSON, whole html code goes to JSON.
Can I directly interpret StreamReader for this purpose or I need to save parsed HTML to string and then perform the operation I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HtmlAgilityPack library to parse HTML and extract what you need to save into a separate file.

I.e.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmltablestring);

foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']")) { 

 streamWriter.WriteLine(table.OuterHtml);

}
```

New Project URL: http://html-agility-pack.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H

Comment: Look at my example code, does your table have an Id or class, is it the only table in the string

Comment: OK, change @ id to @ class and replace table2 with the class name, in my example

Comment: OK, change the selected node to "//table" and try again

Comment: Label1.Text += table.InnerHtml;

Comment: This is exception detail: Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long.

Comment: Ok got the issue, change .Load to LoadHtml

Comment: Now I am getting this error : 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'LoadHtml' and no extension method 'LoadHtml' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The code is working now but I'm getting only one <td> as output. This is my code: http://i.imgur.com/7D5C1b8.png and this is output screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FjbLlRv.png

Comment: What do you want to see, the full table HTML?

Comment: Use OuterHtml instead of InnerHtml

Comment: I want to see the whole table. I tried OuterHtml also I am still getting the same output.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) now its working, I added table class and code is working perfect now!